# build.properties in SBT multi-project build

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a multi project build , the structure of the project looks like this:

- project

  - build.properties
  - plugins.sbt
- subprojects

  - subProj1

    - project/

      - build.properties

Now can we have 2 different sbt versions in 2  build.properies files ? Like we use sbt 0.13 in root project and 1.3 under subProj1 ? Or do sbt ignores the build.properties file for subprojects like it uses to do with **plugins.sbt** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.properties` is only relevant to the sbt [launcher](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package) script which downloads appropriate version artefacts. After sbt ["mother ship"](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4503#issuecomment-450586222) is launched then `sbtVersion` should not be modified anymore as per `inspect sbtVesion`:

```
> inspect sbtVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 1.4.7
[info] Description:
[info]  Provides the version of sbt.  This setting should not be modified.
```

Considering project structure in OP, after sbt is launched at the root level, then `build.properties` files other than `<root>/project/build.properties` will be ignored.